# AnimeJS TranslateY:0 jumps off page

Tags: javascript, css, anime.js

Using *AnimeJS*...

When `active=true` the element animates as expected, starting from below the page and moving up.

When `active=false` the element is supposed to transition back to it's starting position below the page, but instead seemingly jumps far below the page before returning back to 0.

**Sass**

```css
.modal
    --modalHeight: calc(100vh - 80px)
    --modalTransition: calc(-1 * var(--modalHeight))
    position: fixed
    height: var(--modalHeight)
    bottom: var(--modalTransition)
```

**Javascript**

```sass
handleModal(active){
    const modalTransition = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('div.modal')).getPropertyValue('--modalTransition')

    if(active){
        anime({
            targets: 'div.modal',
            translateY: [0, modalTransition],
            duration: 800,
            easing: 'easeOutQuad',
        })
    } else {
        anime({
            targets: 'div.modal',
            translateY: [modalTransition, 0],
            duration: 800,
            easing: 'easeOutQuad',
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer was to convert the CSS `calc()` value to an integer value by replacing the `modalTransition` value with:

```
const modalTransition =
    -Math.abs(parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('div.modal')).height))
```